# How to assign the value of a key as pandas row value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given this datframe:

```
{'index': {0: 0, 1: 1},
 'speed': {0: {'value': ['3'], 'comment': ''},
  1: {'value': ['2'], 'comment': ''}},
 'rotor': {0: {'value': ['2'], 'comment': ''},
  1: {'value': ['3'], 'comment': ''}}}
```

How can I get only the `value` key as this output:

```
 pd.DataFrame({'index': [0,1],'speed': [3,2],'rotor': [2,3]})
```

I tried `df.apply(lambda x: x.get('value')` and `df.apply(lambda x: x.get('value'), axis=1` and no success

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the columns and to use [`str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) (or `str['value']`):

```
cols = ['speed', 'rotor']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.get('value'))
```

Output:

```
   index speed rotor
0      0   [3]   [2]
1      1   [2]   [3]
```

If you only want the integer value:

```
cols = ['speed', 'rotor']

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.get('value').str[0]).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   index  speed  rotor
0      0      3      2
1      1      2      3
```

Alternative using [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
cols = ['speed', 'rotor']

df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: int(x['value'][0]))
```